# Can't seem to stop my .CSS selectors to overstack

Tags: css, joomla

CMS: Joomla 3

My website is partly being displayed on IE9 and below it. I came to the conclusion that I have problem with .CSS selectors. So I used a popular Joomla extension called JCH Optimize which combined my .CSS files. I thought that's where my problem ends, but I was wrong.

I've tested every .CSS file I have and saw no overflow of selectors.
So I implemented a script in one of my pages to find out browse my .CSS files.

That's the page I used to test it -
http://triptop.co.il/index.php/countries-and-places/371

It shows my all of my .CSS files and then this -

```
File: inline <style> tag

Rules: 16

Selectors: 15711
```

How did I end up with 15,711 selectors?  Were my files combined somehow into a < style > header? I must be doing something wrong, or missing something that one of you experts might point me to.

Please, I'm trying to figure it out for a week.

Comment: I get three "Inline <style>" outputs in the console, with 7, 16 and 0 selectors respectively.

Comment: And still, I get the above console log. The weird thing is, I get that log on every website I try.

Comment: My main issue, is that I can't display my website properly on IE9 and below it. Someone must know why.